# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200 ElasticSearch Firebase

Tags: elasticsearch, firebase

From the firebase elastic search project flashlight: https://github.com/firebase/flashlight.git

I imported data from example/seed/data.json into my https://flashlighttest.firebaseio.com

I run this in root:

```
FB_NAME="flashlighttest" node app.js
```

I got this error.

```
failed to index firebase/user/bruce: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
failed to index firebase/user/chan: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
failed to index firebase/user/chuck: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
failed to index firebase/user/kaiso: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
failed to index firebase/user/kato: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
failed to index firebase/user/musashi: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1030:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9200 }
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1030:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9200 }
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1007:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1030:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9200 }
```

After, i run `serve` in the example folder and open http://localhost:3000/. Then, any words that I searched, I got 0 result with this error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "address": "127.0.0.1",
    "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
    "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
    "port": 9200,
    "syscall": "connect"
  },
  "total": 0
}
```

I know that this error happens in lib/PathMonitor.js the _childAdded function.

```
_childAdded: function(key, data) {
      var name = nameFor(this, key);
      this.esc.index(this.index, this.type, data, key)
         .on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('indexed'.green, name);
         })
         .on('error', function(err) {
            console.error('failed to index %s: %s'.red, name, err);
         })
         .exec();
   },
```

Can someone tell me of what went wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because ElasticSearch is not running in my localhost. After I download the elasticsearch and run `bin/elasticsearch` everything is working fine.